# Convert pickle file from protocol 3 to protocol 2

Tags: python-3.x, protocols, pickle

I dumped a pickle file using protocol 3, the default used by python3, but while deploying it on Google cloud which works on python2 , so i need to convert pickle file to protocol 2 . Now i  want to directly convert this pickle file of protocol3 to pickle file of protocol 2. How to do ?

Comment: I would be surprised if python2 could read python3 pickles. I think your options are to dump in the 2 format or run python 3 in gcp.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like below?

I did not find any direct converter in standard. May be someone can.

Load the file into object `obj` and then do the following.

```
pickle.dump(obj, fileObject, 2)
```

There is an option to pass to dump function:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump

Rough code:

```
import pickle

with open('data1.pickle', 'rb') as f1:
    data = pickle.load(f1)

with open('data2.pickle', 'wb') as f2:
    pickle.dump(data, f2, 2)
```